# UIAlertView Metadata

Tags: ios, authentication, uialertview

I am writing an alert view that asks for a username and password, however, I want to use those credentials in a NSURLAuthenticationChallenge* that got passed in from

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

Is there any way to call a UIAlertview and save the challenge variable temporarily inside of it so that I can use it later when the delegate method of the UIAlertView is called? It seems inelegant to use a property or instance variable.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"got authorization challange");

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {

        UIAlertView * loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Enter your Username and Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In", nil];
        loginAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
        [loginAlert show];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid username/PW" message:@"Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Login"] &&
                        buttonIndex == 1)
    {
    /*want to use the challenge variable here to log in the user over the secure connection*/
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text password:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of instance variables (ivars), and by extension, properties, is to maintain object state.

Keeping track of the challenge variable in an ivar is quite appropriate. The `UIAlertView` class doesn't support a way to associate arbitrary data so using an ivar is fine.

You could make use of Objective-C's associated objects but in a case like this there is little reason not to use an ivar to maintain such state.